# How do you convert optional text input to Int in Swift 2, Xcode 7 beta using if let - toInt does not work

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm having trouble converting optional input String to Int in order to do calculations on it.

```
let odoField = UITextField() // allows entry of text to iOS field
odoField.text = "12500" // simulated input
let odoString = odoField.text

// now here is where I get trouble...

if let odoInt = odoString.toInt() {
    distance = Double(odoInt)
}
```

Apparently the toInt suffix is no longer part of Swift. I have tried the following:

```
if let odoInt = Int(odoString)() {
```

But then I get the error "Optional type String? is not unwrapped" and a suggestion to put a ! or ?, as in:

```
if let odoInt = Int(odoString!)() {
```

But then I STILL get the euro about unwrapping, with the suggestion that I add yet another !, then when I do that, another error that I get rid of the parens, like this:

```
if let odoInt = Int(odoString!)! {
```

And then I get ANOTHER error that "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Int'."

I'm trying to create conditional unwrapping, here.

Help!

Comment: why are you putting `()` after the `Int(odoString!)` initializer? Just doing `if let odoInt = Int(odoString!) {` should work. If you want to be safe about unwrapping `odoString` you could even do `if let odoString = odoString, odoInt = Int(odoString) {`.

Comment: Thanks. Adding the first ! (and not the second one) and eliminating the parens worked. It was one combination I did not try. Is it "nil safe"? I don't understand the logic of your second solution. What do the two statements do? Obviously what I am trying to do is both initialize and "conditionalize" odoInt to make it nil safe.

Comment: So the first solution will still forcefully unwrap the string. If the string is nil it will crash your app. The second solves this by first unwrapping the string safely and then using the safely unwrapped string to safely unwrap the created int.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to understand is that UITextField.text returns an *optional* string, so in your code, `odoString` is of type `String?`. Also, keep in mind that the `Int` constructor takes a `String`, not a `String?` so you have to unwrap the `String?` before you can use it. Just putting a `!` after the variable (as in `Int(odoString!)`) will crash your app if the `odoString` is `nil`. Better would be something like this:

```
if let s = odoString, odoInt = Int(s) {
    // odoInt is of type Int. It is guaranteed to have a value in this block
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why simply passing what may be a nil value from 'odoString' to 's' makes 'odoInt = Int(s)' any more nil safe. What magic is going on? In other words, if 'UITextField' is not (yet) completed, then 'odoField.text' is nil, which means 'odoString' is nil, which means 's' is nil, which puts us back in the same situation. It was my impression (as a newbie) that 'if let' turned the following statement into a kind of combination initialization and boolean test for a value, something like "if Int(odoString) is True, then assign it to odoInt and proceed." Where is the magic?

Comment: If odoString is nil, then s will not be created and will not be passed to the Int initializer. So "if odoString != nil, s = odoString! Then if s != nil, odoInt = s!

Comment: @jshuler: Daniel T is correct. That is how the `if let...` construct works.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested Daniel T's answer and it worked.

I have a situation where I want to get the result of a text field back as an optional Int. You can extend this to cover your case using the following code:

```
let odoInt = odoField.text != nil ? Int(odoField.text!) : nil
if let odoInt = odoInt {
    // Use unwrapped odoInt here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option - for a more compact solution - is to use a flatMap:

```
let number = odoString.flatMap { Double($0) } ?? 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it appears that the answer in Swift 2 (Xcode 7 beta 6) is simpler than anything above. The code does not choke on a nil value for odoString when I do e.g. the following:

```
if let odoInt = Int(odoString!) {
    distance = Double(odoInt)
}
```

I therefore surmise, barring deeper knowledge to the contrary, that the compiler does treat this as "if the statement is True (the right side is valid), then define and initialize the variable, and continue with execution." I welcome further feedback. This does render unnecessary a lot of the extra code that is suggested above.

Comment: If `odoString` is nil, this code will crash. Maybe that's exactly what you want, but maybe not.